# Display data from table B after select option from table A

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to display some data from table foom after select option from table factory. The select option is populated data from table factory.

The table design as the image below:

Image 1 = table factory

Image 2 = table room

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fkul13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/67627652_10216715742219103_7514783099603910656_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_oc=AQlMmOMeBy1Df7KLPA4wau2H6a6Le-vtbWBAYHbJGWH83WBFVwmC7jA2ojHykVFMJ5M&_nc_ht=scontent.fkul13-1.fna&oh=e09ae64ad9cd1710f515aab4ddace8ba&oe=5DD5813A))</sub>

[image: Table Room]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fkul13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/67583444_10216715742699115_7846249597264461824_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_oc=AQnR1332aHN2JvrYCnevkf13t62yOiJkNnIP73G2MI0n4NPy6J49OEc8-jr5nD0pi6k&_nc_ht=scontent.fkul13-1.fna&oh=2ed60f06aeff87030c2bd65ccc188d70&oe=5DA08FE1))</sub>

Here is my code for populate select option from table Factory only:

```
<p>Select Factory:</p>
            <?php
            
            if($stmt = $link->query("SELECT * from factory")){

              echo "<select  id='exampleFormControlSelect1' name='Fac_Name' class='form-control'>";
              while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<option value=$row[Fac_ID]>$row[Fac_Name]</option>";
              }
              echo "</select>";
              }else{
              echo $link->error;
              }
            ?>
```

If I select F05, I want to display all rooms that belong to F05 which are MR1 and MR2 in a PHP table.

Comment: Hint: try to use JOIN

`SELECT * from factory LEFT JOIN table2 ON factory.Fac_Name = table2.Room_Desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to recommend to use ajax and create new file for execute room . You factory select have id `exampleFormControlSelect1` so call ajax when ***select change***

```
$(document).on('change', '#exampleFormControlSelect1', function() {
    var selectFactory = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
       url: 'executeRoom.php', // that is optional name
       method: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: { facId: selectFactory },
       success: function(d) {
         var roomOptions = "";
         for(var i in d) {
           roomOptions += "<option>" + d[i].columnName + "</option>";
         }
         $("#roomSelect").html(roomOptions); // you should create select element for your room data
       }
});
```

executeRoom.php

```
<?php
$facId = $_GET['facId'];
$result = [];
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * from room where Fac_ID = ?");
$stmt->execute($facId);
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
     $result[] = ['facId' => $row['Fac_ID'], 'facName' => $row['Fac_Name']];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: OP is using MySQLi, but your answer uses PDO. Generally it is a good idea to pick PDO over mysqli, but OP might already have his code written in MySQLi and the answer should reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

> I'll use [PDO connection](https://www.zentut.com/php-pdo/pdo-connecting-to-mysql/)

```php
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

$GetFactory = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM factory");
$GetFactory->execute();

echo '<form method="POST">';
echo '<select id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="Fac_Name" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">';
foreach($GetFactory->fetchAll() as $factory){
       echo '<option value="{$factory[Fac_ID]}">{$row[Fac_Name]}</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($_POST['Fac_Name'])){

   echo '<hr>';

   $GetRoom = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM room WHERE Fac_ID = ?");
   $GetRoom->execute([$_POST['Fac_Name']);
   foreach($GetRoom->fetchAll() as $room){
     echo '<p>';
     echo $room['Room_Desc'];
     echo '</p>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Link is fixed, my bad

Comment: Thanks. By the way I would avoid linking to this website. The tutorials there are very low quality and suggest very poor programming practices. If you want a good tutorial about PDO check out this website: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: To be honest, i took first one link, with good code for connection :)